# A simple C program without #include <stdio.h>

Tags: c, assembly, printf, mingw, inline-assembly

How to call "printf" directly without including stdio.h ?

I found a interesting tutorial here:
http://www.halcode.com/archives/2008/05/11/hello-world-c-and-gnu-as/

So, here's my attempt:

```
int main(){
 char ss[] = "hello";

 asm (
  "pushl %ebp ;"
  "movl %esp, %ebp ;"
  "subl $4, %esp ;"
  "movl $ss, (%esp) ;"
  "call _printf ;"
  "movl  $0, %eax ;"
  "leave ;"
  "ret ;"
 );

 return 0;
}
```

I'm using MinGW 4.4, and here's how I compile it:

> gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o
>   ld hello.o
>   -o hello.exe C:/mingw/lib/crt2.o C:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/crtbegin.o
>   C:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/crtend.o
>   -LC:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0 -LC:/mingw/lib -lmingw32 -lgcc -lmsvcrt -lkernel32

Unfortunately, it fails:

> hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `ss'

How to fix this?

Comment: why should you need to ?

Comment: @Ahmed - Is learning forbidden? Is the acquisition of knowledge frowned upon?

Comment: well, just pure curiosity
i know practically it's not important

Comment: You cant just paste the assembler output into a C program. for e.g. your 'ret' is just a return statement. the first 2-3 lines inside your asm block, setup the stack, you should not do this inside a c program since the CRT already inserts such code for every function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
    char ss[] = "hello";

    __asm(
        "pushl %[ss]\n"    // push args to stack
        "call _puts\n"
        "addl $4, %%esp\n" // remove args from stack
        :: [ss] "r" (ss)   // no output args, no clobbered registers
    );

    /*  C equivalent:
        extern int puts(const char *);
        puts(ss);
    */
}
```

Comment: @minseong __asm() allows you to call inline assembly code. Most commonly seen in OS programming (I guess really the most common place to see ANY assembly code). here is a decent write up on it: http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly

Comment: @rady which language? Your computer's? Or does it use something else?

Answer (score 10):

You can copy the declaration of `printf` into your program.  In C, including other file is a mere copy-pasting its text into your program.  So you can do this job by doing the copy-paste on your own.

```
extern int printf (const char* format, ...);

int main()
{
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Linker will surely find the proper definition in the libraries, against which you program is linked by default.

Comment: While this works for answering the OP's question, it neatly misses the OP's intention, which is more along the lines of how to work with inline assembly with GCC than it is really about using a function without including a header.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: hey, don't depict me as a fraud! :-)  I answered in the way I understood.  Anyway, my one makes a good second-after-accepted answer. :-)

Comment: @anta40, that's what you get when you entrench in the notion that some language features like #include do magic.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {

    char ss[] = "hello";
    char *p = ss;

    asm (
        "movl %0, (%%esp);"
        "call _printf;" : "=r" (p)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is called Inline assembly. More info here: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: That's dangerous in-line assembly. %esp points to the top element of the stack NOT the next free element. You may have clobbered whatever is at the top of the stack like that. You should push the arg then pop it after.

Comment: doh ! You're right. Ofcource then we'd have to explain to OP calling conventions. :*>

Comment: That works too. Thank you. Yeah, I still neet to learn those calling conventions, since I'm an asm noob.

BTW, when is change ss into "hello world", the output is ".
Why?

Comment: look at the example from Christoph - he removes also the args from the stack

Answer (score -4):

Its very ease
Write one c program using printf statement then
save the program with .c extension
and Run the program 
It will work....
Even it can contain function like clrscr(), getch() which are part of conio.h